# Feeling agitated and stressed after a days worth of coding

Tags: stress

I wanted to know if anyone experiences feeling agitated after a days coding; weighed down by the sense of enormity of the project you are on? Also, any suggestions for dealing with this.

Some days it's happening to me even if the day went quite well; lots done and no real major bugs or hurdles to overcome.

Thanks x

Comment: I can sympathize with your frustration - but this isn't really a good topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I know, the lack of tags was a hint but I thought I'd ask anyway; in the end I could code more effectively. I'm presuming that maybe a few on here have been though something similar. I have a hunch that this might be something people who code for a living may understand better than anyone. ????

Comment: Sounds like you are [burned out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnout_(psychology)). Step back, take a vacation, don't overwork yourself.

Comment: You may have just shown me the forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say take emotional responsibility only for the part you are assigned to, set realistic expectations at the start of the day and celebrate success at the end of the day if you met those expectations. If the work is well organized, then everything should fall in place at the end of the project. If the work is not well organized, then .. well take charge or find better organized projects.

Personally I'm actually jealous of you being able to spend a whole day coding, it seldom happens to me.

Comment: "it seldom happens to me" - me too; I've just been at this thing for 5 weeks now. I suppose it will be over soon. I'm certainly not used to it.

Comment: I'm on my own with it too.